# Methods and classes to use GIF images in android

Tags: android, gif

I want to use `GIF` images in `android`.
I could not find a suitable tutorial which defines which classes or methods to use for using `GIF` images in android
and I want to play the respective `GIF` images in android on click of a button?

I am new to android please help.

Comment: use Glade library for GIF image loading

Comment: can play GIF on dialog on button click

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use Glide library.
Also exist solution with WebView which support gifs but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

> You can play GIF Image without using any library.Refer to the
>   following code:

xml:

```
  <com.jaldihealthy.SampleView
        android:id="@+id/gif_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>
```

SampleView Class:

```
public class SampleView extends View {

    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Context context;

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    public void setmMovie(String url,Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(url);
    }

    public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
        setFocusable(true);

      /*  java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.girl_dances);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);*/
    }

    public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrSet, defStyle);
        setFocusable(true);

       /* java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.girl_dances);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);*/
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }
            int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() / 2 - mMovie.width() / 2,
                    getHeight() / 2 - mMovie.height() / 2);
            invalidate();
        }
    }


    public void showDialog() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyTheme);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

        private Exception exception;
        InputStream is;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                String url = urls[0];
                SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();

                is =  new URL(url).openStream();
                mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;

                return null;
            }
            return is;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream is) {
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed
            dismissDialog();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    }
```

Pass url for your gif:

```
 gif_view.setmMovie(url,mContext);
```